# Can't get html table columns to align in Firefox, works in IE though?

Tags: html, firefox, html-table

I need someone to help point out the obvious to me...been looking for hours and can't figure this out.  The table header columns are not aligning properly in Firefox, but they align fine in IE 7.  I want the table headers to be left aligned with the table data.  Why doesn't this work in Firefox 3?

HTML:

```
<table width="700" align="center" class="ui-corner-bottom background_grey border_bottom_blue border_left_blue border_right_blue">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><table width="600" align="center" style="margin-top: 25px;" class="ui-corner-all background_white border_all_grey" id="line_items">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left">Property</th>
                        <th align="left">Account Number</th>
                        <th align="left">Description</th>
                        <th align="left" colspan="2">Total Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="display: block;" id="clone_me">
                        <td align="left"><input type="text" onclick="new_edit_area('modal_popup_detail', 'HTML_bills_new', '', 'modal_popup_detail', 'html.acctg.bills.php', 'sql_acctg_bills.php');$('#modal_popup_detail').dialog('option','width',800).dialog('option','title', 'Property - Add').dialog('open');" class="item_detail" id="property_id" title="no"></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <select class="input_editable_white item_detail" name="acctg_chart_of_accounts_id_n" id="acctg_chart_of_accounts_id">
                                <option selected="selected" value="1">1100 - Management Operating Account</option>
                                <option value="2">1101 - Petty Cash</option>
                                <option value="3">1102 - Security Deposit Account</option>
                                <option value="4">1103 - Trust Account</option>
                                <option value="5">1104 - Credit Card</option>
                                <option value="6">1200 - Accounts Receivable</option>
                                <option value="7">1201 - Accounts Payable</option>
                                <option value="8">1300 - Mortgage Escrow</option>
                                <option value="9">1301 - Undeposited Funds</option>
                                <option value="10">1400 - Mortgage Principal</option>
                                <option value="11">1401 - Pet Deposit</option>
                                <option value="12">1402 - Security Deposit</option>
                                <option value="13">1500 - Bank Transfer</option>
                                <option value="14">1501 - Owner Contribution</option>
                                <option value="15">1502 - Owner Draw</option>
                                <option value="16">1600 - Adjustment</option>
                                <option value="17">1601 - Application Fee</option>
                                <option value="18">1602 - Bank Interest</option>
                                <option value="19">1603 - Common Area Maintenance</option>
                                <option value="20">1604 - Convenience Fee</option>
                                <option value="21">1605 - Discount/Promotion</option>
                                <option value="22">1606 - Fee for Bounced Check</option>
                                <option value="23">1607 - HOA Fees</option>
                                <option value="24">1608 - Late Fee</option>
                                <option value="25">1609 - Laundry Room</option>
                                <option value="26">1610 - Maintenance Fee</option>
                                <option value="27">1611 - Management Income</option>
                                <option value="28">1612 - Management Income - Cleaning</option>
                                <option value="29">1613 - Opening Balance</option>
                                <option value="30">1614 - Prepayments</option>
                                <option value="31">1615 - Refunds</option>
                                <option value="32">1616 - Rent</option>
                                <option value="33">1617 - Sales Tax Due</option>
                                <option value="34">1618 - Security Deposit Forfeit</option>
                                <option value="35">1619 - Taxes Due</option>
                                <option value="36">1620 - Utilities</option>
                                <option value="37">1621 - Utility Charge</option>
                                <option value="38">1700 - Advertising</option>
                                <option value="39">1701 - Bad Debt/Uncollectible</option>
                                <option value="40">1702 - Bank Fees</option>
                                <option value="41">1703 - Cleaning and Maintenance</option>
                                <option value="42">1704 - Common Area Maintenance</option>
                                <option value="43">1705 - Insurance</option>
                                <option value="44">1706 - Leasing Fee</option>
                                <option value="45">1707 - Legal and Professional</option>
                                <option value="46">1708 - Management Fees</option>
                                <option value="47">1709 - Mortgage Interest</option>
                                <option value="48">1710 - Other Interest</option>
                                <option value="49">1711 - Reconciliation Discrepencies</option>
                                <option value="50">1712 - Repairs</option>
                                <option value="51">1713 - Repairs-Upgrades</option>
                                <option value="54">1713 - Utility Expense</option>
                                <option value="52">1714 - Supplies</option>
                                <option value="53">1715 - Tax Expense</option>
                            </select></td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text" style="width: 20px;" class="input_editable_white item_detail" title="no" name="description_n" id="description"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text" style="width: 20px;" class="input_editable_white item_detail" name="amount_curr_n" title="no" id="amount_curr"></td>
                        <td align="right"><img width="10" height="10" class="a_hand" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" title="Remove" src="images/delete.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="5"><img onclick="add_item();" class="a_hand" title="Add" src="images/plus_green.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="bottom" align="right"><span onclick="var xx=update_new('xml/xml_update_db.php', 'bill_info_main', 'SQL_insert_one_bill', 'new', 'sql_acctg_bills.php','true'); update_multi_row('xml/xml_update_db.php', '', 'item_detail', 'SQL_insert_bill_item_detail', 'new', 'sql_acctg_bills.php','acctg_bill_id',xx,,true); display_html('xml/display_html.php', 'main_container', 'HTML_bills_display','SQL_SELECT_all_bills', '', '', 'html.acctg_bills.php', 'sql_acctg_bills.php');" title="Add"><span class="universal_pad"><span class="a_hand FIELD_name button_text_bg ui-corner-all">Add</span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The best thing you could do is get firebug, and check the actual CSS being applied to your elements. It will also show you the padding/margin on the elements. Otherwise post a screenshot or a jsbin example here.

Comment: P.S Why do you have a `display:block` in your `tr` tag?

Comment: It should be display:none until I clone it..."block" was turned on to help me debug the layout problem.  does it look normal in your firefox browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display` value for the `tr` tag should not be `block`. Change it to `table-row`, and your table should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 <th align="left">
```

with

```
 <th style="text-align:left;">
```

Comment: do you have any table reference in your stylesheet files?

Comment: This is the only css reference to a table:table {
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}..........but if I cut n paste the table into another file that has no css rules and view it in firefox I get the same layout problem, so I don't understand what's going on here.  Thanks for your help.